# Encoding of POST Data

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, post, encoding

I am programatically trying to POST to a web-service. The issue I face is with my data that I post.
Despite

```
string post_data = "man=HE&game=01&&address=123 Main St.&cap=1,2,3,4";
new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes( post_data )
```

it is not getting converted to

```
man=HE&game=01&&address=123+Main+St.&cap=1%2C2%2C3%2C4
```

What is the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

You are only getting a byte stream that way. In order to URL encode the string you could use the [URLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpUtility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) helper class:

```
 string post_data = "man=HE&game=01&&address=123 Main St.&cap=1,2,3,4";

 string[] postTokens = post_data.Split(new Char [] {'&'});
 for(int i = 0; i < postTokens.Length; i++)
 {
    int pos = postTokens[i].IntexOf("=");
    string name = postTokens[i].Substring(0, pos);
    string value = postTokens[i].Substring(pos + 1);

    postTokens[i] = String.Format("{0}={1}", name, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value));
 }     

 string encodedPostData = String.Join("=", postTokens);

 var encodedPostDataBytes = ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(encodedPostData);
```

Comment: In this example, they would need to encode individual parameters, not the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing ascii encoding with url encoding.

You'll want to use [System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and encode each element of the query string separately.

```
string post_data = 
    "man=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("HE") +
    "&game=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("01") // and so forth
```